# Struggling to find solution: question 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help with this problem ?
$$\cos(x)\cos(y)dx + (\sin(x)\cos(y) − \sin(x)\sin(y) + y) dy = 0$$

---

I have tried to find an integrating factor but in the book shows only how to find the integrating factors dependent on one variable (either x or y): so this fails both theorems and is seeming to be dependent on both the variables. I've been struggling with this for a while now, so any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to modify your question to include what you have tried. For example, how did you search for an integrating factor?

Comment: I have tried to find an integrating factor but in the book shows only how to find the integrating factors dependent on one variable (either x or y): so this fails both theorems and is seeming to be dependent on both the variables. I've been struggling with this for a while now, so any help is appreciated

Comment: Try the method at this [link](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/differential-equations/first-order-equations/integrating-factors).

Comment: @SirDancealot You should edit your comment into the question. Also, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty.

Comment: Done and done, but still my problem continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos(x)\cos(y)dx + (\sin(x)\cos(y) − \sin(x)\sin(y) + y) dy = 0$$
Without the $y$ term:
$$\cos(x)\cos(y)dx + (\sin(x)\cos(y) − \sin(x)\sin(y)) dy = 0$$
$$\cos(y)d(\sin x) + \sin(x)d(\sin(y)) + \sin(x)d(\cos(y)) = 0$$
$$\cos(y)d(\sin x)  + \sin(x)d(\cos(y))+ \sin(x)d(\sin(y)) = 0$$
$$d(\cos(y) \sin (x)) + \sin(x)d(\sin(y)) = 0$$
$$\dfrac {d(\cos(y) \sin x)}{\cos(y) \sin (x)} + \dfrac {d(\sin(y))}{\cos(y) } = 0$$
Integrate both sides.
$$\ln {|\cos(y) \sin (x)|} +\int  \dfrac {du}{\sqrt {1-u^2} } = C$$
Where $u=\sin y$.

---

Maybe the $y$ term is a trigonometric function and there is an error in the differential equation.